# Displaying no specific condition in pivot

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to know as in the below code, is it possible to put * instead of specifying the date in "for attendance_day IN ('23-oct-16', '24-oct-16')" and if null, a sepcific value to appear

```
select *  
from 
(
   select STUDENT.id, student_name, attendance_day, attendance_type_id
   from attendance RIGHT JOIN student ON (ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID = STUDENT.ID)
) src

pivot
(
  sum(attendance_type_id)
  for attendance_day IN ('23-oct-16', '24-oct-16')
) piv;
```

This is my attendance tabele and student table

```
Create Table attendance
(
   student_id number (4),
   attendance_day date,
   attendance_type_id varchar2 (10)
);

Create Table student
(
   student_id number (4),
   student_name varchar2 (20),
   nationality varchar2 (10)
);
```

Comment: Not directly.  That would be a dynamic pivot and requires dynamic SQL.  You will probably find examples if you google "Oracle dynamic pivot".

Comment: thanks, i researching on it.. gaining idea how dynamic works..

Comment: sir, if i use dynamic pivot it result in xml, but i would not like in xl as it is not in readable form